# The simplest way to give one person private git access to a code at a VPS public_html dir

Tags: git

We have some code in a public_html dir at a VPS. 
I want to make it git repo and give private access to it to just 1 person.
The idea is to have version control for easy comparison of what this person changed and nobody else to be able to read/write to the code.

I spend the day looking into gitosis, gitolite and so on, but they are overkill and also want separate dir under another user and then I should do some complicated linking to the existing one between bare and not-bare repo, so kinda got lost there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may setup a [git-shell](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell.html)-only account with access to the single `public_html` repository. If you make this repository read-only for that (via simple file/group permissions of the .git/* files), the user will effectively get a read-only access to it.

Comment: that user should have read and write but no one else should be able to even read.

Comment: Then give him/her read-write access as usual. Since the access to the repository is performed via SSH (that is, git transport over SSH) then you'll get the required level of security.

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question, but how does that 1 person would access the repo then? What url he would use or he will need to ssh first?

Comment: Ahh, Ok. ssh access to git repositories is performed with plain git (it has builtin support of SSH-transport), and URLs look like `ssh://user@host/path/to/repo` or simply user@host:/path/to/repo. If a user uploads his/her public SSH key to the server, then he or she may access the repo even without entering the password. See e.g. this [tutorial](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server)

Comment: I did it and it works with a test project under the git user I created following the tutorial. But when I "ln -s" link that project dir to the one under the other user in public_html it starts giving "fatal: '~/project' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
"

Comment: Well SSH may have it's own security precautions against symlinks. I would suggest to specify the full path to the `public_html`, reorganize folders structure so that `public_html` be in the $HOME of that user (remember you can change the location of user's home directory in `/etc/passwd`!) or just setting an alias in Apache' s conf files